# Proof of uniquely determined integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a = qb+r$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, real-numbers

I want to prove the following:

> If $a,b$ are integers, $b >0$ then there are uniquely determined integers q and r such that $a = q\cdot b +r$ and $\frac{-b}{2}<r\leq\frac{b}{2}$.

Is my proof correct:

Suppose $a = q\cdot b +r$ and $\frac{-b}{2}< r \leq \frac{b}{2}$

Then we can see if we divide by $b$: $\frac{-1}{2}< \frac{r}{b} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Then we add $\frac{1}{2}$ to the inequality: $0< \frac{r}{b} + \frac{1}{2} \leq 1$

Because $a = q \cdot b + r \iff \frac{a}{b}-q = \frac{r}{b}$

We can write the inequality as: $0< \frac{a}{b}-q + \frac{1}{2} \leq 1$

We subtract $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{2}$ and we get: $\frac{-a}{b}-\frac{1}{2}< -q\leq 1-\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{2} $

Then we get:
$$(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{2})-1\leq q < \frac{a}{b} + \frac{1}{2} $$

Now my question would be what does the upper inequlity imply?

**Does it imply the floor or the ceil function for $(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{2})$.** ?

However whichever it is means that $q$ is an unique integer and thus $r$ is also an integer since $a$ is an integer and $r = a - q \cdot b$ because integers are closed under addition, subtraction and multiplication.

**Is the proof correct ?**

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but generally uniqueness is proved like this : consider $q_1,q_2,r_1,r_2$ satisfying the hypothesis such that $a= bq_1+r_1 = bq_2+r_2$ and show that $q_1=q_2$ and $r_1=r_2$

Comment: @Infinity_hunter So what I tried to do is to show that $q$ can only be one integer (unique) by the inequality $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{2}-1 < q \leq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{1}{2}$. Because there can only be one unique integer that the upper inequality satisfies right ?

Comment: You can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not allowed to comment I'm posting answer.

As tempting as it is, it is a very bad idea to start a proof with the same statement that you're actually trying to prove. In doing so you get new insights and a better understanding of the problem, but most often the proof doesn't work and never elegant.

Having said that your last line is definition of *greatest integer function*:
$$x-1 \lt [x] \le x$$